# Custom cursor drawn on canvas in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a canvas you can draw on in vanilla JavaScript. I managed to make it so you can draw on it. However, I want to make it so you can see the dot that will be drawn if you press down. I basically want a circle that has the same styling as the drawn lines to follow the cursor. This circle is only supposed to show when it is on the canvas.

I tried a lot of solutions I found on the web, but none of them worked for me. I also set the cursor to none so a custom one could be drawn in JavaScript.

Here are the necessary parts of the HTML and JavaScript code:

```js
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img;

function handleImage(e){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event){
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
      var ratio = this.height / this.width;
      canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio;
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
    img.src = event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}

var pos = { x: 0, y: 0 };

document.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition);
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', setPosition);

function setPosition(e) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  pos.x = e.clientX - rect.left
  pos.y = e.clientY - rect.top
}

function draw(e) {
    canvas.style.cursor = "none";
    if (e.buttons !== 1) return;
    console.log(pos.x)
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#c0392b';

    ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
    setPosition(e);
    ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);

    ctx.stroke();

    canvas.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="imageLoader"/>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most performant way to do this is to set the [CSS `cursor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) to a custom image:

```js
const imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
const canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let img;

function handleImage(e) {
  // avoid data:// URLs at all costs, they are completely inefficient
  img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    var ratio = this.height / this.width;
    canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio;
    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    URL.revokeObjectURL( img.src );
  };
  img.onerror = function(e) {
    console.error( "invalid image file" );
    URL.revokeObjectURL( img.src );
  }
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL( imageLoader.files[ 0 ] );
}

const pos = { x: 0, y: 0 };
// a simple object to keep the current pen styles
const pen_style = {
  color: "#FF0000",
  cap: "round",
  radius: 5,
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  cursor_url: null
};
// update the pen-style object, and the cursor 
document.querySelector( "fieldset" ).oninput = updatePenStyle;
// do it once now to update the cursor
updatePenStyle();

document.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition);
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', setPosition);

function setPosition(e) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  pos.x = e.clientX - rect.left
  pos.y = e.clientY - rect.top
}

function draw(e) {
  if (e.buttons !== 1) return;

  ctx.beginPath();
  // use the values stored in our pen_style object
  ctx.lineWidth = pen_style.radius;
  ctx.lineCap = pen_style.cap;
  ctx.strokeStyle = pen_style.color;

  ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
  setPosition(e);
  ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);

  ctx.stroke();
}

function updatePenStyle() {
  // grab the new values
  const rad = pen_style.radius = pen_radius.value;
  const color = pen_style.color = pen_color.value;
  const cap = pen_style.cap = pen_cap.value;
  // reuse the same canvas every time
  const cursor_canvas = pen_style.canvas;
  const cursor_ctx = cursor_canvas.getContext( "2d" );

  // update the canvas's drawing
  cursor_canvas.width = cursor_canvas.height = rad;
  cursor_ctx.fillStyle = color;
  if( cap === "round" ) {
    cursor_ctx.arc( rad / 2, rad / 2, rad / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2 );
  }
  else {
    cursor_ctx.rect( 0, 0, rad, rad );
  }
  cursor_ctx.fill();
  // extract it as a png image
  cursor_canvas.toBlob( function( blob ) {
    // revoke the previous blob URL we created (if any)
    URL.revokeObjectURL( pen_style.cursor_url );
    // store the new one
    pen_style.cursor_url = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
    // use it as CSS 'cursor'
    canvas.style.cursor = `url(${ pen_style.cursor_url }) ${ rad/2 } ${ rad/2 }, auto`;
  });  
}
```

```css
canvas { background: lightgray }
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Drawing pen settings</legend>
  <label>
    <input type="color" id="pen_color" value="#FF0000">Color
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <select id="pen_cap">
      <option selected>round</option>
      <option>square</option>
    </select>Cap Style
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="30" value="10" id="pen_radius">Width
  </label><br/>
</fieldset>
<input type="file" id="imageLoader"/>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <canvas id="imageCanvas" width="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

Over other solutions, this has the **big** advantage of not needing to repaint the whole canvas, nor anything else in the page. The CSS cursor is at a very special place in the rendering pipeline since it is the last thing to be drawn, and given it is supposed to move all the time, browsers optimize its rendering a lot, which is not too hard to do since it's unlinked to the rest of the page's rendering (it's always at the top).
An other advantage is that it requires almost no memory. Both the canvas and the image are only the size of the cursor which will probably not grow too big.

One disadvantage of this though is that this cursor is static, you can't have sparkling fires or any animations in there.
Also, and probably more of a problem for OP, you may notice that when moving the mouse quickly the canvas drawing has some difficulties to be as fast as the cursor...
That's because drawing the cursor is so much faster.

If these disadvantages are killing point, then you have two other solutions:

**Clear all - Redraw all**.

That's a good general advice, it allows to write easier to maintain code, to better handle various states and layers etc.
However redrawing the full stage every time the mouse moves (even if it's generally limited to the screen-refresh rate), is an over-kill.
Moreover when from [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66786945/how-do-i-apply-context-filter-only-to-the-image-on-the-canvas) we can guess you'll also have complex filters going on.

**Do it like the browser does**

As we hinted at the beginning of this answer, the browser rendering is actually made of various layers, each [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) will be its own layer, rendered on its own canvas. Only the ones that are in the current viewport will get composited to produce a new bigger layer. Once this final layer has been composited the browser will clip it to the viewport and will just finally draw the cursor over this clipped and composited layer.
So the next time the cursor moves, the browser will just have to take that last state of the final composition and draw the cursor at its new position.

Well we can use the same logic at our level.

We can keep in memory an HTMLCanvasElement on which we'll perform all the drawings (the final compositor), and every time the cursor move, we'll draw that hidden canvas on an other one, visible, where we'll just have to draw the cursor after.

```js
const imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
const visible_canvas = document.getElementById('visibleCanvas');
const visible_ctx = visible_canvas.getContext('2d');
// create a copy of the canvas that we'll keep disconnected from the DOM
const hidden_canvas = visible_canvas.cloneNode();
const hidden_ctx = hidden_canvas.getContext('2d');

let img;

function handleImage(e) {
  // avoid data:// URLs at all costs, they are completely inefficient
  img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    const ratio = this.height / this.width;
    const width = visible_canvas.width;
    const height = visible_canvas.height = width * ratio;
    hidden_canvas.width = width;
    // draw the image on the hidden canvas
    hidden_ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0, width, height );
    URL.revokeObjectURL( img.src );
  };
  img.onerror = function(e) {
    console.error( "invalid image file" );
    URL.revokeObjectURL( img.src );
  }
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL( imageLoader.files[ 0 ] );
}

const pos = { x: 0, y: 0 };

document.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition);
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', setPosition);

function setPosition(e) {
  const rect = visible_canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  pos.x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  pos.y = e.clientY - rect.top;
}

function draw(e) {
  const color = "red";
  const radius = 5;
  
  if (e.buttons === 1) {

    // do the drawings on the hidden context
    hidden_ctx.beginPath();
    hidden_ctx.lineWidth = radius;
    hidden_ctx.lineCap = "round";
    hidden_ctx.strokeStyle = color;

    hidden_ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
    setPosition(e);
    hidden_ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);

    hidden_ctx.stroke();

  }
  else {
    // hasn't been updated yet
    setPosition(e);
  }
  // even when not dragging, but only if over the canvas
  if(
    pos.x < visible_canvas.width && pos.x > 0 &&
    pos.y < visible_canvas.height && pos.y > 0
  ) {
    visible_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, visible_canvas.width, visible_canvas.height );
    // draw the hidden canvas on the visible one
    visible_ctx.drawImage( hidden_canvas, 0, 0 );
    // draw the cursor
    visible_ctx.beginPath();
    visible_ctx.arc( pos.x + radius / 2, pos.y, radius / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2 );
    visible_ctx.fillStyle = color;
    visible_ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

```css
canvas { cursor: none; background: lightgray; }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="imageLoader"/>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <canvas id="visibleCanvas" width="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here what's nice is that the hidden canvas can stay as a pure bitmap and can be drawn on the visible canvas as fast as possible. It still is far less performant than the CSS cursor solution, but it avoids a huge overhead.

You could even go further and keep some parts of your drawing on their own canvas, like the browser does with all its stacking contexts, and update only the one layers that need to be updated (image / text / drawing etc.)
However beware that this solution has a big memory footprint, since you actually duplicate the bitmap buffers.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a lot more to this than I'm willing to get into at the moment, but I've included some code for you to study. Good Luck!

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC, StateMaker, Can; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = (node, className)=>{
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = function(node, ...classNames){
  node.classList.add(...classNames);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(node, ...classNames){
  node.classList.remove(...classNames);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(node, className){
  node.classList.toggle(className);
  return tC;
}
StateMaker = function(initialState){
  var o = initialState;
  if(o){
    this.initialState = o; this.states = [o];
  }
  else{
    this.states = [];
  }
  this.savedStates = []; this.canUndo = this.canRedo = false; this.undoneStates = [];
  this.addState = function(state){
    this.states.push(state); this.undoneStates = []; this.canUndo = true; this.canRedo = false;
    return this;
  }
  this.undo = function(){
    var sl = this.states.length;
    if(this.initialState){
      if(sl > 1){
        this.undoneStates.push(this.states.pop()); this.canRedo = true;
        if(this.states.length < 2){
          this.canUndo = false;
        }
      }
      else{
        this.canUndo = false;
      }
    }
    else if(sl > 0){
      this.undoneStates.push(this.states.pop()); this.canRedo = true;
    }
    else{
      this.canUndo = false;
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.redo = function(){
    if(this.undoneStates.length > 0){
      this.states.push(this.undoneStates.pop()); this.canUndo = true;
      if(this.undoneStates.length < 1){
        this.canRedo = false;
      }
    }
    else{
      this.canRedo = false;
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.save = function(){
    this.savedStates = this.states.slice();
    return this;
  }
  this.isSavedState = function(){
    var st = this.states, l = st.length; sv = this.savedStates;
    if(l !== sv.length){
      return false;
    }
    function rec(o, c){
      var x, z;
      if(typeof o !== typeof c){
        return false;
      }
      else if(o instanceof Array){
        for(var n=0,q=o.length; n<q; n++){
          x = o[n]; z = c[n];
          if(x && typeof x === 'object'){
            return rec(x, z);
          }
          else if(o !== c){
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      else if(o && typeof o === 'object'){
        for(var n in o){
          x = o[n]; z = c[n];
          if(x && typeof x === 'object'){
            return rec(x, z);
          }
          else if(o !== c){
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      else if(o !== c){
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
    for(var i=0; i<l; i++){
      if(!rec(st[i], sv[i])){
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
Can = function(output, readyFunc){
  const upload = M('input'), oS = output.style, drawArray = [];
  let img, draw = false;
  this.stateMaker = new StateMaker; oS.display = 'flex'; oS.justifyContent = 'center';
  this.output = output; this.canvas = M('canvas'); this.ctx; upload.type = 'file'; 
  upload.accept = 'image/*';
  this.uploadImg = ()=>{
    upload.click();
    upload.onchange = ()=>{
      const files = upload.files;
      if(files.length){
        const file = files[0];
        if(file.name.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i)){
          if(img)img.remove();
          img = M('img');
          const b = this.output.getBoundingClientRect(), h = b.height;
          const s = img.style, c = this.canvas, o = this.output;
          s.position = c.style.position = 'absolute';
          img.onload = ()=>{
            const w = img.width/img.height*h;
            c.width = w; c.height = h; s.width = w+'px'; this.ctx = c.getContext('2d'); this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            this.stateMaker.states.splice(0);
            if(readyFunc)readyFunc.call(this);
          }
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file); o.appendChild(img); o.appendChild(c);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  const xy = e=>{
    const c = this.canvas, b = c.getBoundingClientRect(); 
    return [e.clientX-b.left, e.clientY-b.top];
  }
  this.render = ()=>{
    const n = this.canvas, c = this.ctx, s = this.stateMaker.states;
    c.clearRect(0, 0, n.width, n.height);
    for(let a of s){
      c.beginPath(); c.moveTo(...a[0]);
      for(let i=1,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
        c.lineTo(...a[i]); c.stroke();
      }
    }
  }
  const downFunc = e=>{
    if(!draw){
      const c = this.ctx, q = xy(e);
      c.beginPath(); c.moveTo(...q); draw = true;
      drawArray.splice(0, drawArray.length, q);
    }
  }
  const moveFunc = e=>{
    const c = this.ctx, q = xy(e);
    if(c){
      if(draw){
        c.lineTo(...q); c.stroke(); drawArray.push(q);
      }
      else{
        this.render(); c.beginPath(); c.moveTo(...q); c.lineTo(...q); c.stroke();
      }
    }
  }
  const upFunc = ()=>{
    if(draw){
      draw = false; this.stateMaker.addState(drawArray.slice());
    }
  }
  if(mobile){
    this.canvas.ontouchstart = e=>{
      downFunc(e.touches[0]);
    }
    ontouchmove = moveFunc; 
    ontouchend = ()=>{
      this.render(); upFunc();
    }
  }
  else{
    this.canvas.onmousedown = downFunc; onmousemove = moveFunc; onmouseup = upFunc;
    this.canvas.onmouseout = ()=>{
      if(!draw)this.render();
    }
  }
  onresize = ()=>{
    if(img){
      const b = this.output.getBoundingClientRect(), h = b.height, c = this.canvas;
      const o = this.output, w = img.width/img.height*h;
      c.width = w; c.height = h; img.style.width = w+'px';
      this.ctx = c.getContext('2d'); readyFunc.call(this); this.render();
    }
  }
}
// Library above - magic below can be put on another page using a load Event *(except // end load line)*
const output = I('output'), upload = I('upload');
const can = new Can(output, function(){
  const c = this.ctx;
  c.lineCap = 'round'; c.lineWidth = 7; c.strokeStyle = 'red';
});
upload.onclick = can.uploadImg;
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0; font-size:0; border:0; outline:none; overflow:hidden;
}
html,body,.full{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#333;
}
#page{
  padding:7px;
}
canvas{
  cursor:none;
}
#output{
  height:calc(100% - 46px); background:#000;
}
button{
  cursor:pointer; width:100%; height:46px; background:linear-gradient(#1b7bbb,#147); color:#fff; font:bold 28px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; padding:5px; border:1px solid #007; border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Draw Example</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='full' id='page'>
    <div id='output'></div>
    <button id='upload'>Select a File</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that `can.stateMaker` supports undo, redo, and save. So, in the example, each line drawn is actually adding a separate state. Although I haven't included it in the example, when you do like `can.stateMaker.undo()`, just `can.render()` and it will take away a single line.