# How do I apply context.filter only to the image on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a photo editor where you can upload an image, add filters, put on text, draw with a pencil, etc. The problem is that the filters that I want on just the image, applies to everything on the canvas. I don't want it to apply to the text and the drawn lines with a pencil. Is this even possible in vanilla JS or would I have to use a library?

This is how I it looks right now when the text color is actually set to red and I applied grayscale:
[image]

This is how I want it to look with red text and grayscale applied:
[image]

This happens with all of the other filters as well, but gray scale was the most obvious one, so I used that as an example. I did not include code as I am mainly asking if this is even possible.

Comment: No, this is not possible, [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#filters) says: "_All drawing operations on an object which implements the CanvasFilters interface are affected by the global filter attribute._". You've to use a separate canvas to draw unfiltered images.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, just set the `ctx.filter` back to `"none"` after you've drawn the image.